# How to merge two queryset on specific column

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

Hello I am using a postgres database on my django app.

I have this model:

```
class MyFile(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        default=python_uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
        unique=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
    path =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.ManyToManyField(Device, through='FileStatus')
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    when = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    canceled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    group = models.UUIDField(
        default=python_uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
```

What I want is to group my MyFile by group, get all the data + a list of file associated to it.

I managed to get a group associated to a list of file with:

```
MyFile.objects.all().values('group').annotate(file=ArrayAgg('file', ordering='-when'))
```

which is giving me a result like:

> [{'group': 'toto', 'file':['file1', file2']}, ...]

I can also get all my MyFile data with:

```
MyFile.objects.all().distinct('group')
```

What I want is to get a result like:

> [{'group': 'toto', 'file':['file1', file2'], 'when': 'ok', 'path':
> 'ok', 'user': 'ok', 'status': [], canceled: False}, ...]

So I fought I could merge my two queryset on the `group` column but this does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works

```
MyFile.objects.values('group').annotate(file=ArrayAgg('file', ordering='-when'))
```

Comment: This is the same as  MyFile.objects.all().values('group').annotate(file=ArrayAgg('file', ordering='-when')) and won't bring new data to the result :/